# Post request fails with some curl commands but not with others

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, curl

I have a post route set up in node like so:

```
router.route('/').post((req, res) => {
  pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', req.body, (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${result.insertId}`);
  });
});
```

If I use this curl command, it works perfectly and the user is added:

```
curl -d "username=Dinesh Chugtai&email=dinesh@piedpiper.com&password=test" http://localhost:4000/users
```

However, when sending a post request through Postmate, I get this error:
`ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Postmate also generates a curl command, which is this one:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:4000/users?username=johnsmith&email=john@smith.com&password=password'
```

If I type that manually in the command line, it also gives me the same error.

Why does one curl command work and the other doesn't? Is my post route set up correctly?

Comment: I think it would help people better answer your question if you included the dollarshaveclub/postmate command you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Node.js route definition, you're expecting to get the data in the `req.body` which is the body of the POST request.

- The first `curl` works because you're putting data in the **body**
- The second fails because in you're putting data in the **query parameters** (in the URL itself)

Comment: This was it! Thank you